# Input value update dilemma

Tags: javascript, html, css

so i was trying to achieve a program that changes the width and height of an image based on the user's input, i could achieve that normally, but i wanted to do it using object-oriented programming, so here's my problem: i need to get the value of my input elements when the "material" function is called, but if i move the input elements inside the function, the "sett" will not work properly as i've used the input elements before defining them, and if i move the "sett" to the bottom of my code then the "material"'s "caller" parameter will not work because again i've used "sett" before defining it.
here's my code:

also i forgot to remove the "top" and "left" input elements in the html code, so consider anything associated with them as nothing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style>
#brazil {position:absolute;display:none;width:200;height:200;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<input id="width" type="text" placeHolder="width"/>
<input id="height" type="text" placeHolder="height"/>
<input id="top" type="text" placeHolder="Vertical Position"/>
<input id="left" type="text" placeHolder="Horizontal Position"/>
<input type="button" value="Create" onclick="material(sett)"/>

<br>
<img id="brazil" src="brazil.png" alt="brazil"/>



<script>


var  Cons = function(width,height) {
this.width = width;
this.height = height;
}

var brazil = document.getElementById("brazil");

var nwidth = document.getElementById("width").value;
var nheight = document.getElementById("height").value;


var sett = new Cons(nwidth,nheight);

var  material = function(caller) {

brazil.style.width = caller.width;
brazil.style.height = caller.height;
brazil.style.display = "inline";

}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In simple words, you're getting the value from the inputs at pageload only, when the value is just an empty string.

Comment: i know that, i explained it on the top, but there must be some way ?

Comment: Sure there is, you need to get the inputs values when the button is clicked, there's really no way around that.

Comment: yes i've also explained that on top but i want to know how to get the input values when the button is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have different problems. In the end I think you look for this:

```
var Cons = function(width, height) {
  this.width = width + 'px';
  this.height = height + 'px';
}

var material = function(caller) {
  brazil.style.width = caller.width;
  brazil.style.height = caller.height;
  brazil.style.display = "inline";
}

var brazil = document.getElementById("brazil");
var nwidth = document.getElementById("width");
var nheight = document.getElementById("height");
var button = document.querySelector('input[type="button"]');



button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    var sett = new Cons(nwidth.value, nheight.value);
    material(sett);
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/7c20kwjm/

What I did:

- changed the logic with `nheight` and nwidth` so you don't cache the value, but the DOM element
- added a event listener so you can pass abd run the functions in the correct order
- added `+ 'px'` to the Class/Object so it renders correctly

---

PS. welcome to visit also the [Portuguese Stackoverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style>
        #brazil {position:absolute;display:none;width:200;height:200;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="width" type="text" placeHolder="width"/>
    <input id="height" type="text" placeHolder="height"/>
    <input id="top" type="text" placeHolder="Vertical Position"/>
    <input id="left" type="text" placeHolder="Horizontal Position"/>
    <input type="button" value="Create" onclick="material(sett())"/><br>
    <img id="brazil" src="brazil.png" alt="brazil"/>
    <script>
        var  Cons = function(width,height) {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        };
        var brazil = document.getElementById("brazil");
        var sett = function(){

            return new Cons(document.getElementById("width").value,document.getElementById("height").value)
        };

        var  material = function(caller) {

            brazil.style.width = caller.width;
            brazil.style.height = caller.height;
            brazil.style.display = "inline";

        }


    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Modifying your sett to a function should also work!!!